# Regex for checking if a string contains "`" character

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I'm trying to check if a string contains this character `` ` ``.

And if the character is found, to wrap that string between `<div>`.

For example:

```
`this is it
```

should become:

```
<div>this is it</div>
```

And I've tried to do it but it seem to not work:

```
let arr = "`this is it";
if (arr.includes('`')) {
  arr = arr.replace(/\`(\w+)\`/g, '<div>$1</div>');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try ``arr.replace(/`([^`]+)`?/g, '<div>$1</div>')``

Comment: Unrelated but you can't reassign `const` variables

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and as such does not match with the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that the backtick should only appear at the beginning of the line. If it is also needed at the end, add another one before the `$` in the regex.

I also presume that your string is multiline, and any line can start with a backtick. If not, remove the `m` flag.

If there can be more than one backtick-delimited substrings in a line, make the `*` quantifier non-greedy with `?` and remove the `^` and `$` assertions. If such substring can span several lines, also add `s` flag.

```js
let arr = "`this is it";
arr = arr.replace(/^`(.+)$/mg, '<div>$1</div>');
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
arr.replace(/`([^`]+)`?/g, '<div>$1</div>')
```

The regex matches

- `` ` `` - a backtick
- `` ([^`]+) `` - one or more chars other than backtick
- `` `? `` - an optional backtick

**JavaScript demo**

```js
const arrs = ["`test` is `here`","`this is it"];
const regex = /`([^`]+)`?/g;
for (const arr of arrs) {
  console.log(arr, '=>', arr.replace(regex, '<div>$1</div>'));
}
```